# trying to total gridview in asp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am trying to total the price and quantity of all the products added to the gridview and i can't seem to figure out why the total is not showing in the footer. the code that i have for the vb should multiply the quantity with the price and put it into the footer of the gridview. the gridview footer is visible so i know that's not the problem. any help would be appreciated.

asp:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataSourceID="Cart" AllowSorting="True" BackColor="White" 
    BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
    GridLines="Vertical" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" DataKeyNames="cartID">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="cartID" HeaderText="cartID" SortExpression="cartID" 
        InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="cartNO" HeaderText="cartNO" SortExpression="cartNO" 
        Visible="False" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="productID" HeaderText="productID" 
        SortExpression="productID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="productName" HeaderText="productName" 
        SortExpression="productName" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="price" 
        SortExpression="price" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="quantity" HeaderText="quantity" 
        SortExpression="quantity" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SubTotal" SortExpression="subTotal" >
        <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("price") * Eval("quantity")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
       <%-- <FooterTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="sum" runat="server"/>
        </FooterTemplate>--%>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

VB
    Public Class MyCart

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim strcartNO As String = ""
    Dim cookieBack As HttpCookie
    cookieBack = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("cartNO")
    strcartNO = cookieBack.Value
    'sqldscartLine.selectCommand = "Select * from cartLine where cartNO = '" & strcartNO & "'"
    GridView1.DataBind()


End Sub

Public Shared Sub DeleteMethod(ByVal original_OrderID As Integer, _
ByVal original_ProductID As Integer)

End Sub



Dim priceTotal As Decimal = 0
Dim quantityTotal As Integer = 0
Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        ' add the UnitPrice and QuantityTotal to the running total variables
        priceTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, _
         "price"))
        quantityTotal += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, _
          "quantity"))
    ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "Totals:"
        ' for the Footer, display the running totals
        e.Row.Cells(3).Text = priceTotal.ToString("c")
        e.Row.Cells(4).Text = quantityTotal.ToString("d")

        e.Row.Cells(3).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
        e.Row.Cells(4).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
        e.Row.Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your original source code have the footer commented out too? - you have your footer wrapped in <%-- --%>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anybody saw the comment, so will put it in an answer instead - This might help others out (if I'm correct..)

Your code has the following in

```
 <%-- <FooterTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="sum" runat="server"/>
    </FooterTemplate>--%>
```

The `<%--` and `--%>` are comments, so your footer is being commented out.

Change it to

```
 <FooterTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="sum" runat="server"/>
    </FooterTemplate>
```

And it should display.

Answer (score 0):

Databinding creates data rows.  The footer isn't a data row, so the event `RowDataBound` is not called when it's created.  Thus, your event handler `GridView1_RowDataBound` will never execute the code that generates the totals, since the expression

```
e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer
```

... will never be true during any execution of that method.

Try handling the `RowCreated` event instead, like so:

```
Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "Totals:"
        ' for the Footer, display the running totals
        e.Row.Cells(3).Text = priceTotal.ToString("c")
        e.Row.Cells(4).Text = quantityTotal.ToString("d")

        e.Row.Cells(3).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
        e.Row.Cells(4).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
        e.Row.Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub
```