# Asp.net display sum of columns total in gridview footer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a program that uploads an excel file. After uploading the value of excel file will be transferred in gridview.

What I want to do is to get the total value per column and will be placed in footer.Does anyone can help me with this? Thank you.

Here's what I have so far.

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fl As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
        GridView1.DataSource = OpenExcelFile(fl)
        GridView1.DataBind()
        savetoDB(OpenExcelFile(fl))
 End Sub

Protected Function OpenExcelFile(ByVal fileName As String) As Object
    Dim dataTable As New System.Data.DataTable()
    Dim exl As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & exl & ";Extended Properties=" & """Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"""
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [NAME],[FIL],[ENG],[SCI],[MTH]", connectionString)
    adapter.Fill(dataTable)
    Return dataTable
End Function

Protected Sub savetoDB(dt As System.Data.DataTable)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("myconnectionhere")
    Dim dt2 As New System.Data.DataTable
    dt2 = OpenExcelFile(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)

    Using bulk As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(con)
        bulk.DestinationTableName = "studnt_table"
        bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("[NAME]", "st_name")
        bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("[FIL]", "sbj_fil")
        bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("[ENG]", "sbj_eng")
        bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("[SCI]", "sbj_sci")
        bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("[MTH]", "sbj_mth")
        con.Open()
        bulk.WriteToServer(dt2)
        con.Close()
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

**And here is my front end**

here is the sample layout I want to achieve. I want to get the sum of the columns in line and display the total in footer. Does anyone knows how can I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you/

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add total in VB.Net Gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828558/add-total-in-vb-net-gridview)

Comment: This maybe a duplicate with other question but can't find solution in my case. Thank you. Also checked the link you posted still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I've only added sample for 1 column to get an idea. Extend the `OpenExcelFile` after `adatapter.Fill(dataTable)`  [IsNull Check](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ak67st4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
adatapter.Fill(dataTable)
Dim sumRow As DataRow
Dim Col1Tot,Col2Tot,Col3Tot,Col4Tot As Decimal 

For Each row1 As DataRow In dataTable.Rows  
   If Not row1.IsNull("FIL") Then 
     Col1Tot =  Col1Tot + Convert.toDecimal(row1("FIL"))
   End If 
   If Not row1.IsNull("ENG") Then 
     Col2Tot =  Col2Tot + Convert.toDecimal(row1("ENG"))
   End If 
   If Not row1.IsNull("SCI") Then 
     Col3Tot =  Col3Tot + Convert.toDecimal(row1("SCI"))
   End If   
   If Not row1.IsNull("MTH") Then 
     Col4Tot =  Col4Tot + Convert.toDecimal(row1("MTH"))
   End If 
Next row1

'Do the remaining columns in same way   
'Finally add it to the Datatable as a new row
sumRow =  dataTable.NewRow()
sumRow("FIL") = Col1Tot 
dataTable.Rows.Add(sumRow)

sumRow =  dataTable.NewRow()
sumRow("ENG") = Col2Tot 
dataTable.Rows.Add(sumRow)

sumRow =  dataTable.NewRow()
sumRow("SCI") = Col3Tot 
dataTable.Rows.Add(sumRow)

sumRow =  dataTable.NewRow()
sumRow("MTH") = Col4Tot 
dataTable.Rows.Add(sumRow)

return dataTable;
```

Let us know your findings.

Comment: Omygaad this is a life saver! Thank you so much. But I have another concern what if the value of the columns contains decimal and what if the column is blank. Tried it if the column is blank it returning an error.

Comment: haha, I've updated the sample/answer to check DbNull and also convert to decimal.Again only on one column. Good luck.

Comment: sorry for asking you so many question I'm really new in asp.net and I'm still exploring. How can I simply my if statement in all the column? And also the decimal is not working I mean it returns total value without computing the decimal. thank you. and once again sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by *it returns total value without computing the decimal.*

Comment: instead of example the grades are. 81.2, 82.3, 85.5, 90.3 the answer should be 339.3 it returns 339 only.

Comment: Ah ya the update should do the trick. I had the `Col1Total` as `Integer` previously  instead of `Decimal`. It should do it correctly now.

Comment: OMYGAD. Thank you so much. you saved me! Thank you.